# Move a word from a line to another of the same file text

Tags: bash

I have a text file and I want to move "/A" from line 507 to line 561 of my text.
I will put just a part of my file text.

This is the example:

```
A NAME="23_09_15at12_37_00_comp_sum_mismatch" < /A >

<data>
-----------------
Mismatch analysis
-------------------------------------------------------------
               Statistics    All_Seqs        Mean        s.d.
-------------------------------------------------------------

Demographic expansion
---------------------
                      Tau        18.6    18.58410     0.00000
              Tau qt 2.5%     7.79899     7.79899     0.00000
                Tau qt 5%    10.53528    10.53528     0.00000
               Tau qt 95%    23.50602    23.50602     0.00000
             Tau qt 97.5%    24.74816    24.74816     0.00000
                   Theta0     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000
           Theta0 qt 2.5%     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000
             Theta0 qt 5%     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000
```

And I want this outcome:

```
A NAME="23_09_15at12_37_00_comp_sum_mismatch"

<data>
-----------------
Mismatch analysis
-------------------------------------------------------------
               Statistics    All_Seqs        Mean        s.d.
-------------------------------------------------------------

Demographic expansion
---------------------
                      Tau        18.6    18.58410     0.00000
              Tau qt 2.5%     7.79899     7.79899     0.00000
                Tau qt 5%    10.53528    10.53528     0.00000
               Tau qt 95%    23.50602    23.50602     0.00000
             Tau qt 97.5%    24.74816    24.74816     0.00000
                   Theta0     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000
           Theta0 qt 2.5%     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000
             Theta0 qt 5%     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000
< /A >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` for the task:

```
sed -e '507s=</A>==' -e '561i\
</A>' input-file > output-file
```

The first command means "on line 507, replace `</A>` with nothing"; the second one means "before line 561, insert `</A>`",

Comment: Actually I wanted to move not only "/A" but "</A>". By the way, when I type the second command,  I have an error ": command i expects \ followed by text. Do you know why?

Comment: @CafféSospeso: Replace `/A` with `</A>`, it should still work. Maybe you have a different sed version/implementation, try putting `\ ` and a newline after the `i`. (The answer updated.)

Comment: I tried to use this command but it give me the same error. I forgot to mention that I'm using a Mac. May it is not the same command than what you proposed.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

Perhaps more readable than `sed` version

```
$ awk -v k="< /A >" 'NR==1{sub(k,"")} NR==20{print k} 1' file
```

I used line numbers 1 and 20 for the test, you can change based on the actual case.  Note that perhaps counting lines is not what you want in the first place but identify from/to locations by some other means, in which case `awk` will give more options...

```
A NAME="23_09_15at12_37_00_comp_sum_mismatch"

<data>
-----------------
Mismatch analysis
-------------------------------------------------------------
               Statistics    All_Seqs        Mean        s.d.
-------------------------------------------------------------

Demographic expansion
---------------------
                      Tau        18.6    18.58410     0.00000
              Tau qt 2.5%     7.79899     7.79899     0.00000
                Tau qt 5%    10.53528    10.53528     0.00000
               Tau qt 95%    23.50602    23.50602     0.00000
             Tau qt 97.5%    24.74816    24.74816     0.00000
                   Theta0     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000
           Theta0 qt 2.5%     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000
             Theta0 qt 5%     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000
< /A >
```

Comment: It works, the only problem is that it doesn't delete the first < /A >, but keep both.

Comment: it has to match the string exactly as written, with the in tag spacing.  If so, perhaps your `awk` has different behavior.